# stop a full background video at the last frame

Tags: jquery, css, html, video, background

I'd like to stop a full background video, right at the last frame, so it looks like a poster image.

this is the html string i have:

```
      <video class="video" preload="true" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted>
          <source src="C:/Users/Paolo/Desktop/site/video/yo.webm" type="video/webm">
      </video>
```

i'm new with this, so i'm kinda noob :P

Answer (score 8):

```
<video id="video" preload="true" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted>
    <source src="C:/Users/Paolo/Desktop/site/video/yo.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

Stopping right at the last millisecond is hard. You can though pause the video *just before* it ends.

```
var videoEl = targetYourVideoElementSomehow;
    
videoEl.addEventListener("timeupdate", function () {
    console.log('checking time...');
    if (videoEl.currentTime > videoEl.duration - 0.5) {
        // 0.5 is seconds before end.
        videoEl.pause();
    }
});
```

Note that the first checks for `videoEl.duration` might give you `NaN` because the video hasn't loaded enough information to give you the full duration of the video.

Comment: I used [`preload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-preload), and got good results with `0.4` (i.e. 400 milliseconds).

Answer (score 3):

This solution worked for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// select your video element
var video = document.querySelector('.video');

// listen for the event that fires when your video has finished playing
video.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    // pause the video
    this.pause();
    // set play time to the last frame
    this.currentTime = this.duration;
}, false);

</script>
```

this.duration (or video.duration) returns the exact time of your last frame.
And like DCdaz said you should remove the loop attribute in your html.

Comment: This does not work on android chrome. For some reason currentTime is 0 all the time.

Comment: I did not have any issues with this approach using the latest version of Chrome on Android. +1 to this solution for being more performant and frame-accurate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `loop="loop"`.

```
video.addEventListener('ended', function() { 
   this.currentTime = 100; 
}, false);
```

Replace 100 with the end time of your video.

Comment: yeah but how can i pause it at the last frame?

Answer (score 1):

Did some research and this solution worked for me. There are always many different ways to do things when it comes to coding.

**HTML**

```
<video id="video" ontimeupdate="pauseVideo(this)" src="./content/video.mp4" muted loop autoplay></video>
```

**Javascript**

```
 <script>
    // Pause video function
    const video = document.getElementById('video');

    function pauseVideo(event) {
        // Console test
        // console.log(video.duration)
        // console.log(event.currentTime)

        // Pause video 0.5 seconds before end time.
        if (event.currentTime > video.duration - 0.5) {
            video.pause();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Basically, what this is doing is using the **ontimeupdate** attribute calling the javascript method every time the video progresses through to the end. Then, I'm using an if statement to check when the **current position** of the video is less than the **total duration** of the video. Once, the video position reaches 0.5 seconds before the duration a.k.a the end of the video is paused.